# Google ML-Kit Label Image bounding Box?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

Hey just a quick question:

I tried out googles ML-Kit for labelling images. It takes my camerafeed (Android.Media.Image) nicely and returns a list of FirebaseVisionLabels. These objects have a getLabel() (a string with the object name) and a getConfidence() (a float from 0 to 1) method to call (as well as an entityId which is some weird position in their decision tree I suppose?)

However I'd rather need a position on the screen, like an XY coordinate to WHERE the stuff which was found, got detected.

I was about to pack my bags and search for another SDK as I discovered some parts of the ML-kit do have that feature. Like the ML-Face Detection comes with a bounding box. But I suppose I can only use that for faces?

How can I build an app which shows me that This specific element right here is called thisName? Is there any way to call something like a

```
FirebaseVisionLabel.getDetectedElementPosition(element)
```